# Handling wcf reference.cs exceptions

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, windows-phone-8

I work with a SOAP WCF webservice under a Reverse Proxy.

Here is the operations i do with the service :

```
public static async Task chargementDonnees(foooooooooo client)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["equipe"] = await Tools.getEquipeTask(client);
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["attelage"] = await Tools.getAttelageTask(client);
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["depart"] = await Tools.getDepartTask(client);
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["heure"] = await Tools.getHeureTask(client);
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["localisation"] = await Tools.getLocalisationTask(client);
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["natureintervention"] = await Tools.getNatureInterventionTask(client);

    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
}
```

And here is an example of function called :

```
public static Task<List<Localisation>> getLocalisationTask(fooooo client)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<Localisation>>();
    client.GetLocalisationCollectionCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
    };
    client.GetLocalisationCollectionAsync();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the exception throw in reference.cs file :

[image]

I'm trying to catch exception send by the webservice, for example if my credential are false. I set a try catch bloc here, but the exceptions are not throw here. It happends it the reference.cs file. Can someone please explain how handle exception throw in reference.cs from webservice ? Thx

How is it possible to secure the use of a WCF webservice under a RP with a WP8 application ?

Comment: Does your `GetLocalisationCollectionCompleted` contain the Exception in case it happened in the `async` method?

Comment: The exception is throw before the application goes into the getLocalisationCollectionCompleted event. I'll edit with a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link talking about catching exceptions with async / await methods :

http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2013/11/10/windows81-async-void-exceptions/